# Save current Google Map view as an image

Tags: image, google-maps, save

I have a database with some addresses. For each address the view of the map will be different.

Is there a way, for each address, to save the map view as an image?

Answer (score 2):

```
 <img src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<?php echo 
 $MyAddress?>CA&zoom=14&size=500x500&markers=<?php echo $myAddress?>&sensor=false' alt=''/>
```

The center is where the map will be centered.
The markers is the address you want so i put center=markers.
Zoom is how close you want to zoom in the map
Size the size you want of the picture.
Take a look here
http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the Google Static Maps API, from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

For storage and bandwidth purposes you can only storage the GeoPoint of the location and only render the image when the user requests it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function getGoogleMapImage($params = array(), $saveTo = null, $https = true){
        //set default parameters
        if(!isset($params['markers'])){
            $params['center'] = isset($params['center']) ? $params['center'] : 0;
            $params['zoom'] = isset($params['zoom']) ? $params['zoom'] : 0;
        }
        $params['size'] = isset($params['size']) ? $params['size'] : '200x200';
        $params['sensor'] = isset($params['sensor']) ? $params['sensor'] : 'false';

        foreach($params as $name => $value){
            $paramString.=$name . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
        }
        $paramString = trim($paramString, '&');

        $httpPrefix = $https ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        $imageUrl = $httpPrefix . 'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?' . $paramString;

        if(!$saveTo){ //if you don't want to save image, just to display it
            return $imageUrl;
        }

        if(isset($params['format'])){
            switch($params['format']){
                case 'png8': $imgExt = '.png'; break; 
                case 'gif': $imgExt = '.gif'; break; 
                case 'jpg': $imgExt = '.jpg'; break; 
                case 'jpg-baseline': $imgExt = '.jpg'; break; 
                default: $imgExt = '.png';
            }
        }else{
            $imgExt = '.png';
        }

        $saveTo = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $saveTo) . $imgExt; //in case requested file extension and provided in $saveTo don't match

        if(self::getImage($imageUrl, $saveTo)){
            return realpath($saveTo);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I used curl call for getting images from created $imageUrl